# Magento 2 add customer address attribute to REST APIs response?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, quote, billing-address

I have created customer address attribute "city_id" with setup script. 
I am able to save the value. but want to display the city_id field to the below apis json response. how we can we add city_id in the response for existing apis?

```
GET /V1/carts/mine/billing-address

GET /V1/guest-carts/:cartId/billing-address
```

I found one reference link https://web4pro.net/blog-news/magento-2-add-custom-attribute-customers-address/ and is this suitable for this requirement?

[image]